# Mac toolbar via WINE / Crossover

Tags: winapi, macos, wine

Does anyone know if it's possible to get a Win32 application to run under wine / crossover but have the main toolbar appear as a Mac toolbar (i.e. outside the wine / crossover app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the "main toolbar"? In Win32, windows do not require a menu bar (ie: IE), or even a main window (!) so this is obviously not possible in general. If you really wanted to, you could send [GetMenu()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647640(VS.85).aspx) to the first created window, then use (something like? I haven't used the menu APIs much) [GetMenuItemInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647980(VS.85).aspx) to fill the mac toolbar whenever the app gains focus, but I think this would be a lot of work for an 80% at best solution, not to mention I wouldn't know where to start to integrate this with WINE or crossover.